# dynamodb column search starts with query

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, loopbackjs

We are using loopback 3 and dyanmodb for our rest API. In one of the query, we want to search name which starts with letters entered by the user. For e.g.:

```
 {
     name: { like: "^" + str}
 },
```

But regexp is not supported in dynamodb. How could I achieve this in dynamodb ? Is there an alternate solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes use the the wildcard symbol `%` which works like `(.*?)` in regex or `*` in windows search

```
 {
     name: { like: str + "%"}
 },
```

This will produce a query that search for `str` and any character after that.

Check [SQL Wildcards](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp)

**Example**

```
   SELECT * FROM WeekDays
    WHERE DayName LIKE 'Mon%'
```

Comment: But dynamodb does not support regular expressions. The above query does not work either.